# GREP REGEX LARGE FILE

Tags: regex, grep, large-files

On a MAC how do I GREP? I have a large TXT file (200MB). The sample data is below. I want to run a GREP with a regex and be able to get ONLY the following data values in my terminal response:

> 00424730350000190100130JEAN DANIELE &

I want everything up to `82700`. Once I have this information, I can copy it into another file for other purpose. Now I just get back tons of information.

Sample Record:

> 00424730350000190100130JEAN DANIELE &                82700 TINEPORK CT                                                                                                                            LAT BORAN AK 12345                                              3342843470224201400003980000002664300001216IWD    QD0415200800004005880002281300000671IWD    QM0330200500004900000001836800000431IWD    QM0325199900002455270001147700000969IWD    QM

sample Grep I wrote:

```
grep -E "^(.*?)82700" MYFILE.TXT
grep -E "^(.*?)[0-9]" MYFILE.TXT
```

This still doesn't work, it gives back tons of info and the `82700` can be any value...I would like it to be Any help suggestions? thank you

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Comment: /[0-9]{23}.+?(?=82700)/ Now instead off entering actual value off '82700' How can any number be there like /[0-9]{23}.+?(?=[0-9)/

Comment: Do you have access to GNU sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sample data

```
grep -E -o "^[0-9]{23}[^0-9]+[0-9]+" MYFILE.TXT
```

seems to do the job:

> 00424730350000190100130JEAN DANIELE & 82700

using **grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD** on **Darwin 14.4.0**.

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.