# PHP how to handle a large while

Tags: php, regex, for-loop, out-of-memory, large-files

I have a 36mb (FILE B) with over 650k lines.I have tried fgets, fopen, file_get_contents and they are not working. I think I am running out of memory. What I am trying to do is, I have file 'A excel (138 lines)', I want to loop  thru it get a value and go find (via regex )it in File B (.TXT - 35MB). Once I have found it in 'File B' , I want to take it write it in 'FILE A'. I went into the .ini changed max memory also and the timer (300). fopen() sample below:

```
$handle = fopen("/Users/jerry/Desktop/info.TXT", "r") or die("Couldn't get handle");
if ($handle) { //IF
    while (!feof($handle)) { //WHILE
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
        //  echo $buffer; //displays the 650k lines
         for ($row12 = 2; $row12 <= 23; $row12++){ //for1
$name3 = $objPHPExcel45->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row12)->getValue() ; 
            $regex144 = "/$name3/";
            preg_match($regex144, $buffer, $try);
            foreach ($try as $h => $wer){//foreach
                echo $wer; echo $row1; echo "<br>";
        //  $nameset = $objPHPExcel45->getActiveSheet()->setCellByColumnAndRow(7, $row12)->getValue() ;
            }//foreach
        }//for 1    
    }//WHILE    
    fclose($handle);
}//IF

File_get_contents option:

$htmlfile = "/Users/deepak/Desktop/info.TXT";
$html1 = file_get_contents($htmlfile);
for ($row3 = 2; $row3 <= 50; $row3++){ 

      $name3 = $objPHPExcel45->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row3)->getValue() ; 
//checking for a initial 
        if (preg_match($renamewithinitials, $name3, $matchesini)) { //1st if

    //flip the name with initials
$names5 = explode(" ", $name3);
$name5 = $names5[2] . " " . $names5[1]. " " . $names5[0];   
$length1 = strlen($name5);
$regex1 = "/[0-9]{23}$name5/";
preg_match($regex1, $html1, $t);
foreach($t as $x22 => $x_value22) {
    echo "lets see if works LION INITIAL: $x_value22"; echo "<br>";
}

//set in excel under a new column 'flip name'
//$objPHPExcel->getSheet(0)->SetCellValueByColumnAndRow(6, $row3,$name5);
} //1st if

  // is there a compnay name
     else { //1st else
        if (preg_match($renamewithinitials2, $name3, $matchesini2)) { //2nd if

//NO name flipping
$name6 = $name3;
//$objPHPExcel->getSheet(0)->SetCellValueByColumnAndRow(6, $row3, $name6);
        } //2nd if


     //is there 2 spaces TWO SPACES TWO SPACES ONLY
        else { //2nd else
        if (preg_match($renamewithTwoSpaces, $name3, $matchesini3)) {//3rd if
        //flip name
            $names8 = explode("  ", $name3);
$name8 = $names8[1] . " " . $names8[0];

$regextwospace = "/[0-9]{23}$name8/";

preg_match($regextwospace, $html1, $t2space);
foreach($t2space as $x2234 => $x_value2234) {
    }
//set in excel under a new column 'flip name'
//$objPHPExcel->getSheet(0)->SetCellValueByColumnAndRow(6, $row3, $name8);
        }//3rd if   
        //is there ONE SPACE ONE SPACE ONLY
        else { //3rd else
        if (preg_match($renamewithOneSpace, $name3, $matchesini4)) { //4th if
        //flip name
            $names9 = explode(" ", $name3);
$name9 = $names9[1] . " " . $names9[0];
$regexonespace = "/[0-9]{23}$name9/";
preg_match($regexonespace, $html1, $tonespace);
foreach($tonespace as $x223 => $x_value223) {
}
//set in excel under a new column 'flip name'
//$objPHPExcel->getSheet(0)->SetCellValueByColumnAndRow(6, $row3, $name9);
        }//4th if
        } //2nd else

                        }  //3rd else   
            } //1st else    
}  //for     
//}
fclose($html1);
//we save
$objWriter45->save($auctionFileExplodeFinal[0].'-DRD-FILE-copy-nosave.xlsx');
```

Comment: running on localhost....

Comment: Convert your file into a database

Comment: What line does the file handler option die at?

Comment: In the file_get_contents around 30.  The Fopen () option code above doesn't work...Maybe my coding is wrong.

Comment: What is the maximum memory limit that I can set? And max execution time?

Comment: How often are you going to be doing this? You're basically using a flatfile database which would be OK of it wasn't so large. With a 36MB file you're just asking for trouble. What if only two people tried running this script? You would definitely benefit by having that large text file of data in a database. I would highly suggest moving away from this train of thought.

Comment: If this is somewhat related to [grep regex large file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439827/grep-regex-large-file), and `grep` is actually able to handle the big file: Perhaps calling a shell script from PHP might be an option.